# Azure storage container (general purpose v2) tells me I can't tag blobs from code

Tags: c#, azure, tags, azure-blob-storage

I've recently started using blob-tagging in our Azure storage containers. It's frustrating that Azurite doesn't appear to support tagging, so I can't fully test these changes locally, but once deployed and hooked up to a general purpose v2 storage container, I still get the following exception:

> Blob tags are only supported on General Purpose v2 storage accounts

Here is our internal function which I'm using to tag the blobs...

```
public async Task SetTagsOnBlobAsync(BlobBaseClient blob, IDictionary<string, string> tags)
{
    await blob.SetTagsAsync(tags).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

We're using the NuGet package `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, v12.16.0.

Here is a screenshot from the Azure portal, showing that the storage account is general purpose v2...

[image]

And yet here is the full exception message when we call the above code:

> Blob tags are only supported on General Purpose v2 storage accounts. RequestId:160b0660-a01e-0047-23d8-8fbf8d000000 Time:2023-05-26T13:46:42.3539235Z Status: 400 (Blob tags are only supported on General Purpose v2 storage accounts.) ErrorCode: BlobTagsNotSupportedForAccountType Content:  BlobTagsNotSupportedForAccountTypeBlob tags are only supported on General Purpose v2 storage accounts. RequestId:160b0660-a01e-0047-23d8-8fbf8d000000 Time:2023-05-26T13:46:42.3539235Z Headers: x-ms-error-code: BlobTagsNotSupportedForAccountType x-ms-request-id: 160b0660-a01e-0047-23d8-8fbf8d000000 x-ms-version: 2022-11-02 x-ms-client-request-id: 41028c76-7b82-4349-b65d-a100a1481c57 Content-Length: 272 Content-Type: application/xml Date: Fri, 26 May 2023 13:46:42 GMT Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

However, I *am* able to add tags on the very same blob by using Azure Storage Explorer.

**UPDATE:**
I *am* able to tag the same blobs from another application - for example, I have an API which uploads documents to blob storage and then attempts to add a tag, which fails, but I *am* able to take that blob (by name) and add the same tag using a simple console application.

I wonder if the problem is timing: Might I be requesting to tag the blob before it fully exists? Immediately prior to the tagging attempt I've called [`BlobClient.UploadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.UploadAsync)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=azure-dotnet), and I wonder if the blob is still uploading or being processed when this method returns and my code moves on to the tagging request?

Comment: Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal#setting-blob-index-tags:

Setting blob index tags can be performed by the Storage Blob Data Owner and by anyone with a Shared Access Signature that has permission to access the blob's tags (the t SAS permission).

In addition, RBAC users with the Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/tags/write permission can perform this operation.

Comment: I'm trying to create the tag immediately after creating it, so 'I' am the owner.

Comment: The message does seem misleading--and there are specific access error messages for each failure in the authentication flow--yet it's possible you have access to the data plane but not the control plane (blob metadata) or vice versa. Try explicitly defining RBAC, say assign the Storage Blob Data Owner to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with @hector-j-rivas, that tags can be added by Storage Blob Data Owner or by anyone with a SAS.

Storage Account Kind:

[image]

I am having Owner rights and below is the code which worked for me:

```cs
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

string cs = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik;AccountKey=pPBWLWkA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
BlobServiceClient bsc = new BlobServiceClient(cs);

string cn = "name of container";
string bn= "name of blob";
BlobContainerClient cc = bsc.GetBlobContainerClient(cn);
BlobClient bc= cc.GetBlobClient(bn);

Dictionary<string, string> t = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Tag-1", "Rithwik" },
    { "Tag-2", "Value2" }
};

await bc.SetTagsAsync(t);
```

[image]
Output:

[image]

Try creating a new storage account and check with that if its works or not, If the issue after giving rights persists, I would suggest you to raise a support request as the above process works for V2 and I got desired output too.